# No ingresa los datos a la tabla

Tags: java, netbeans

me ayudan, en mi programa que debe meter datos a una tabla, pasa que cuando le doy registrar no ingresa los datos a la tabla el error es el siguiente
package registro.de.cliente;

```
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.Calendar;
import javax.swing.Icon;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.filechooser.FileNameExtensionFilter;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;


/**
 *
 * @author JCCM
 */
public class Registro extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 6530913924448000342L;
    public Register data = new Register();
 DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel();

     int cod = data.getCod();
     String name = data.getName();
     String appname = data.getAppname();
     String apmname = data.getApmname();
     int phone = data.getTelephone();
     String time = data.getTime();
     String join = data.getJoin();
     int EP;
     String fecha;

     public void tabla (){

        model.addColumn("Codigo");
        model.addColumn("Nombre");
        model.addColumn("Apellidos");
        model.addColumn("Telefono");
        model.addColumn("Hora Ingreso");
        model.addColumn("Ocupacion");
        model.addColumn("Empresa");
        model.addColumn("Fecha");
        Registro.tdDatos.setModel(model);
     }
    public Registro() {
        initComponents();
           }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel4 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel5 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel6 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel7 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel8 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel9 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel10 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        txtCod = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        txtName = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        txtNameapm = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        txtnameap = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        txtPhone = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        txtJoin = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        cbxEmpresa = new javax.swing.JComboBox<>();
        dchFecha = new com.toedter.calendar.JDateChooser();
        txtTime = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jpPhoto = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        btLoad = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jLabel12 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        cbxSexo = new javax.swing.JComboBox<>();
        btReg = new javax.swing.JButton();
        btNew = new javax.swing.JButton();
        btLogin = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        tdDatos = new javax.swing.JTable();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jLabel1.setText("REGISTRO DE EMPLEADOS CENTRAL");

        jLabel2.setText("CODIGO:");

        jLabel3.setText("Nombres Completos:");

        jLabel4.setText("Apellido Paterno:");

        jLabel5.setText("Apellido Materno:");

        jLabel6.setText("Telefono\\Cel.:");

        jLabel7.setText("Fecha de Ingreso:");

        jLabel8.setText("Cargo\\Ocupacion:");

        jLabel9.setText("Ubicacion de Servicios:");

        jLabel10.setText("Hora:");

        txtCod.addKeyListener(new java.awt.event.KeyAdapter() {
            public void keyTyped(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {
                txtCodKeyTyped(evt);
            }
        });

        txtName.addKeyListener(new java.awt.event.KeyAdapter() {
            public void keyTyped(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {
                txtNameKeyTyped(evt);
            }
        });

        txtNameapm.addKeyListener(new java.awt.event.KeyAdapter() {
            public void keyTyped(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {
                txtNameapmKeyTyped(evt);
            }
        });

        txtnameap.addKeyListener(new java.awt.event.KeyAdapter() {
            public void keyTyped(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {
                txtnameapKeyTyped(evt);
            }
        });

        txtPhone.addKeyListener(new java.awt.event.KeyAdapter() {
            public void keyTyped(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {
                txtPhoneKeyTyped(evt);
            }
        });

        cbxEmpresa.setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel<>(new String[] { "Seleccione Empresa", "ServiCell", "Yimy S.A", "Ambas Empresas", " " }));

        txtTime.addKeyListener(new java.awt.event.KeyAdapter() {
            public void keyTyped(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {
                txtTimeKeyTyped(evt);
            }
        });

        jpPhoto.setText("Imagen");
        jpPhoto.setBorder(javax.swing.BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(null, "Fotografia", javax.swing.border.TitledBorder.DEFAULT_JUSTIFICATION, javax.swing.border.TitledBorder.ABOVE_TOP, new java.awt.Font("Dialog", 0, 11), new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 204))); // NOI18N

        btLoad.setText("Cargar Imagen");
        btLoad.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                btLoadActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jLabel12.setText("SEXO:");

        cbxSexo.setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel<>(new String[] { "Seleccione.....", "Masculino", "Femenino" }));

        btReg.setText("Registrar");
        btReg.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                btRegActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        btNew.setText("Nuevo");
        btNew.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                btNewActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        btLogin.setText("Ver Registro");
        btLogin.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                btLoginActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        tdDatos.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
            new Object [][] {
                {null, null, null, null},
                {null, null, null, null},
                {null, null, null, null},
                {null, null, null, null}
            },
            new String [] {
                "Title 1", "Title 2", "Title 3", "Title 4"
            }
        ));
        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(tdDatos);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jLabel1)
                .addGap(188, 188, 188)
                .addComponent(btLogin)
                .addContainerGap())
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                    .addComponent(jLabel3)
                                    .addComponent(jLabel4)
                                    .addComponent(jLabel2))
                                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                                    .addComponent(txtCod)
                                    .addComponent(txtName)
                                    .addComponent(txtnameap)
                                    .addComponent(txtNameapm)
                                    .addComponent(txtPhone)
                                    .addComponent(dchFecha, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 147, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                                    .addComponent(txtTime, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 124, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                            .addComponent(jLabel5)
                            .addComponent(jLabel6)
                            .addComponent(jLabel7)
                            .addComponent(jLabel10))
                        .addGap(72, 72, 72)
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                                        .addComponent(jLabel9, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                                        .addComponent(jLabel12, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 66, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                        .addComponent(cbxSexo, 0, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, false)
                                        .addComponent(btNew, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                                        .addComponent(btReg, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)))
                                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                    .addComponent(cbxEmpresa, 0, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, false)
                                            .addComponent(btLoad, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 170, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                                            .addComponent(jpPhoto, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                                        .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE))))
                            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addComponent(jLabel8)
                                .addGap(37, 37, 37)
                                .addComponent(txtJoin, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 143, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                        .addGap(20, 20, 20))
                    .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 691, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addGap(31, 31, 31))))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel1)
                    .addComponent(btLogin))
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel2)
                    .addComponent(jLabel8)
                    .addComponent(txtCod, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(txtJoin, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGap(21, 21, 21)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel3)
                    .addComponent(jLabel9)
                    .addComponent(txtName, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(cbxEmpresa, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                                    .addComponent(jLabel4)
                                    .addComponent(txtnameap, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                                    .addComponent(jLabel5)
                                    .addComponent(txtNameapm, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                                .addGap(20, 20, 20)
                                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                                    .addComponent(jLabel6)
                                    .addComponent(txtPhone, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                    .addComponent(jLabel7)
                                    .addComponent(dchFecha, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                                .addGap(10, 10, 10)
                                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                    .addComponent(jLabel10)
                                    .addComponent(txtTime, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addComponent(jLabel12, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 21, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                                .addComponent(cbxSexo, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .addGap(28, 28, 28)
                                .addComponent(btNew))))
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(8, 8, 8)
                        .addComponent(jpPhoto, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 136, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                            .addComponent(btReg)
                            .addComponent(btLoad))))
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 198, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addGap(6, 6, 6))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void btLoginActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        

    }                                       

    private void btRegActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                      


        cod=(Integer.valueOf(txtCod.getText()));
        data.setName(txtName.getText());
        data.setAppname(txtnameap.getText());
        data.setApmname(txtNameapm.getText());
        data.setTelephone(Integer.valueOf(txtPhone.getText()));
        data.setTime(txtTime.getText());
        // fecha
   String dia =  Integer.toString(dchFecha.getCalendar().get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
   String  mes= Integer.toString(dchFecha.getCalendar().get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1);
   String  anio= Integer.toString(dchFecha.getCalendar().get(Calendar.YEAR));
     fecha = dia+mes+anio;
        data.setJoin(txtJoin.getText());
        cbxSexo.getSelectedIndex();
        EP = cbxEmpresa.getSelectedIndex();
       String [] Agregar = new String[8];  

        Agregar[0]= txtCod.getText();
        Agregar[1]= txtName.getText();
        Agregar[2]= data.getAppname()+" "+data.getApmname();
        Agregar[3]= Integer.toString(data.getTelephone());
        Agregar[4]= data.getTime();
        Agregar[5]= data.getJoin();
        Agregar[6]= Integer.toString(cbxEmpresa.getSelectedIndex());
        Agregar[7]= fecha;
        model.addRow(Agregar); 
    }
```

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0"
>   java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Not supported yet.
>         at registro.de.cliente.Register.setTime(Register.java:161)
>         at registro.de.cliente.Registro.btRegActionPerformed(Registro.java:339)
>         at registro.de.cliente.Registro.access$700(Registro.java:24)
>         at registro.de.cliente.Registro$8.actionPerformed(Registro.java:171)
>         at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
>         at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
>         at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
>         at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
>         at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
>         at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6533)
>         at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
>         at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6298)
>         at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)
>         at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
>         at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
>         at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
>         at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4888)
>         at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4525)
>         at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4466)
>         at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2280)
>         at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
>         at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
>         at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
>         at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
>         at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
>         at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
>         at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>         at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
>         at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:90)
>         at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
>         at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
>         at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>         at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:80)
>         at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
>         at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
>         at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
>         at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
>         at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
>         at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
>         at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)

el otro codigo register es este

```
package registro.de.cliente;

/**
 *
 * @author JCCM
 */
public final class Register{
   private int cod;
   private String name;
   private String appname;
   private String apmname;
   private int telephone;
   private String join;
   private String time;


   void Register() {
   setcod(0);
   setname("");
   setappname("");
   setapmname("");
   settelephone(0);
   setjoin("");
   settime("");
    //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }



    void Register(int pcod, String pname, String pappname, String papmname, int ptelephone, String pjoin, String ptime) {
        setcod(pcod);
        setname(ptime);
        setAppname(pappname);
        setApmname(papmname);
        setTelephone(ptelephone);
        setjoin(pjoin);
        setTime(ptime);
    }
    // constructor copia



    /**
     * @return the cod
     */
    public int getCod() {
        return cod;
    }

    /**
     * @return the name
     */
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    /**
     * @param name the name to set
     */
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    /**
     * @return the appname
     */
    public String getAppname() {
        return appname;
    }

    /**
     * @param appname the appname to set
     */
    public void setAppname(String appname) {
        this.appname = appname;
    }

    /**
     * @return the apmname
     */
    public String getApmname() {
        return apmname;
    }

    /**
     * @param apmname the apmname to set
     */
    public void setApmname(String apmname) {
        this.apmname = apmname;
    }

    /**
     * @return the telephone
     */
    public int getTelephone() {
        return telephone;
    }

    /**
     * @param telephone the telephone to set
     */
    public void setTelephone(int telephone) {
        this.telephone = telephone;
    }

    /**
     * @return the join
     */
    public String getJoin() {
        return join;
    }

    /**
     * @param join the join to set
     */
    public void setJoin(String join) {
        this.join = join;
    }

    /**
     * @return the time
     */
    public String getTime() {
        return time;
    }

    public void setcod(int pcod) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }

    private void setname(String ptime) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }

    private void setjoin(String pjoin) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }

    private void setappname(String string) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }

    private void setapmname(String string) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }

    private void settelephone(int i) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }

    private void settime(String string) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }

    void setTime(String text) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }


}
```

Comment: Te recomiendo que aparte de la excepción, publiques un fragmento del código que estas usando para tener un poco mas de informacion

Comment: No entiendo el problema, tienes un metodo setTime que cuando lo invocas levanta una excepción. Tu stacktrace muestra que se invocó ese método y saltó exactamente la excepción esperada

Answer (score 1):

La excepción se presenta porque usaste la función auto generar gets y sets de netbeans, el IDE crea los métodos con una excepción por defecto.

```
throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
```

Lo que debes hacer es completar tu código.

Comment: que le faltaria

Comment: Por ejemplo donde tienes

public void setcod(int pcod) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }

deberias poner el set como los que tienes arriba

 public void setcod(int pcod) {
        this.cod = pcod;
    }

Asi para todos donde tengas el throw new...